# Datastax: where is it hiding Solr logs?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

The standard Solr log file is nowhere to be found under the Solr home directory that comes with the standard Datastax installation. Does anybody know where it's located? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datastax Enterprise "hides" the Solr log in the Cassandra log. Look in /var/log/cassandra. Maybe we need to document that a little more clearly.

The whole point of Datastax Enterprise is to integrate Cassandra and Solr.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used datastax before but it is usually stored in the tomcat folder or whatever server you are running it ob